# Mysterious Cyan target symbol in XCode 6 Beta

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Not sure if NDA allows me to post screenshots of xcode 6 or not, So will try to describe it in words. When I open XCode 6 beta, I see a button sized circle with cyan filler, and crosshair like lines inside it. Does not appear in any other application so I guess thats new feature. Does anyone know its use?

Comment: I don't think the NDA even allows this. Please post to developer forums.

Comment: new NDA allows to discuss anything except posting screenshots. http://daringfireball.net/linked/2014/06/06/apple-nda

Comment: And does anyone know how to get rid of it?  I'm having the same issue in Xcode 5.1.1 although Xcode 6 is installed on the same machine.